# ignore case with regular expression

Tags: .net, regex, sql-server-2005, clr

I have created a CLR in a SQL server 2005 database. It is a simple regular expression user defined function that will check if a pattern exists in the string I pass into the function.

The dot net code I use in the CLR is shown below:

```
Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("Input", "pattern")
```

This returns a bit value of 1 if a match is found.

The pattern I am using is

```
 +(Create|Alter) +(Proc|Procedure) +
```

What I want this to do is find any cases of “create or alter” “procedure or proc” regardless of the case. How can I get the expression to ignore case?

I have tried

```
/ +(Create|Alter) +(Proc|Procedure) +/i
```

but this doesn’t work.

EDIT: I have looked around on the internet and used various suggestions. None of which have worked or I have done them wrong. If someone could give me a pattern that will ignore the case that would be much appreciated!

Answer:
What i was trying to achieve was a regular expression that ignores case. Dot Net does have parameters that can be passed in to set ignore case however it being in a CLR means i do not have the ability to pass the parameters in to the function.

The pattern that achieves this is : (?i) +(Create|Alter) +(Proc|Procedure) +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the inline "case-insensitive" modifier `(?i)`:

```
(?i) +(Create|Alter) +(Proc|Procedure) +
```

Comment: Does that space between (?i) and + make it look for a space?

Comment: That space was part of the origial pattern - so I left it untouched.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for thank you! Tested and works!

The space and the + means that there can be any amount of spaces before the Create or Alter.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it means "at least one space". I tend to use `\s*` or `\s+` in these situations, because a) it's easier to recognize for the human eye and b) it captures other types of white space, too.

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("input", @".*(Create|Alter).+(Proc|Procedure).+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I would recommend installing free software [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to test your regular expressions and generate .Net / c# code for search, replace, etc

Comment: @jcasso: Not sure if your appreciation for an unrelated aside justifies an up-vote. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak: The questioner is having problem with creating a regex. If he used Expresso, he would notice that there is an "IgnoreCase" option. Does not upvote mean it is useful?

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(
    regexStringHere,
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

return regex.IsMatch(inputStringHere);
```

Hope this helps.